# Shell getopt first parameter error

Tags: shell, getopt

Running the following code, I find host_ip is empty, I don't know what the reason is?

```
TEMP=`getopt --long hostip:,hostport: -n 'javawrap' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$TEMP"

host_ip=
host_port=

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    --hostip ) host_ip="$2"; shift 2;;
    --hostport ) host_port="$2"; shift 2 ;;
    * ) break ;;
  esac
done

echo $host_ip
echo $host_port
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to specify the short options to `getopt` otherwise it (IMO) messes up the parsing. From `man getopt`:

> If this  option is not found, the first parameter of getopt that does not start with a '-' (and is not an option argument) is used as the  short  options string.

This works:

```
$ getopt --options '' --longoptions hostip:,hostport: -n 'javawrap' -- --hostip foo --hostport bar
 --hostip 'foo' --hostport 'bar' --
```